# Black-Scholes PDE derivation gap

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-calculus, delta-hedging, black-scholes-pde

Most derivations of the Black-Scholes formula end up with the following dynamics of some (hedged) portfolio:

$$
\int_{t=0}^{T} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}(S(t),t)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(S(t),t)\cdot\sigma^2\cdot S(t)^2\right) \,dt
$$

From then, they argue that this process is locally riskless.

**First Question:** Since this integral can be defined as a pathwise Riemann integral, what stops me  from definying it using right Riemann sums? In this case, I cannot see how it would be riskless at all.

Then, the authors declare this portfolio should earn the risk-free rate, so they get the following identity:

$$
\int_{t=0}^{T} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}(S(t),t)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(S(t),t)\cdot\sigma^2\cdot S(t)^2\right) \,dt = \int_{t=0}^{T} \left(r\cdot\left(V(S(t),t)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(S(t),t)\cdot S(t)\right)\right) \,dt
$$

Fair enough. However, based on this, them they assume the expression within the integrals are equal at al times t.

**Second Question:** Why is this true?

Thank you.

**EDIT: Attempt to answer Second Question:** The identity actually is:

$$
\int_{t=0}^{\lambda} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}(S(t),t)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(S(t),t)\cdot\sigma^2\cdot S(t)^2\right) \,dt = \int_{t=0}^{\lambda} \left(r\cdot\left(V(S(t),t)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(S(t),t)\cdot S(t)\right)\right) \,dt
$$

For all $0\leq \lambda \leq T$

So equality of functions within the parenthesis holds for all $0\leq t \leq T$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ito process representation uniqueness](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2486481/26651) states that, if
$$ \int_0^t Y_u du + \int_0^t Z_u dW_u = 0 $$
for all $T\geq t\geq 0$, then
$$   Y = Z = 0 $$
[almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2486481/26651) (aka up to a set of measure $0$).

In your case, you can take $Z$ to be $0$ and $Y_u:=g(S_u,u)$, where $S$ is your Ito process and $g$ is a deterministic function defined by:

$$ g(x,t) := (\partial_2 V)(x,t) +0.5 (\partial_{11} V)(x,t)\sigma^2 x^2 - r(V(x,t)-(\partial_1 V)(x,t)x).  $$

If $g$ is continuous, we then get that $g(x,t)=0$ for all $x$ and $t$ (null everywhere) by using the following fact: for a random variable $X$ with strictly positive density, if $l$ is continuous such that $l(X)=0$ a.s., then $l=0$ (everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question; nothing prevents you I think, and even something close exists. Without dealing with all the technicalities (I am neither an expert on that), the opposite way of doing stochastic integration, rather than using the Ito-integral, is known as the [Stratonovich integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratonovich_integral).

Similar to your approach of using the right Riemann sums, the Stratonovich integral is not applicable in finance as it needs future information.
One reason for choosing the Ito-integral as it is, comes from the fact that the integral can be calculated with all the information about the process that is know untill a certain point in time.
Given the same information set, the Ito-integral can and your approach cannot be computed as it needs at least one value of the process in future time.

Regarding your second question; it comes due to the no-arbitrage condition.
I will give you the full derivition in a slightly different notation, which will be a bit easier to follow I think.

Consider the portfolio $P$ with the European style option $C(t, S(t))$ and $\Delta$ shares with share price $S(t)$,
$$ P(t, S(t)) = C(t, S(t)) - \Delta S(t) $$
Following the Black-Scholes approach, assume a constant interest rate $r$ and  let the risky asset $S(t)$ be following a geometric Brownian motion with drift $r$ and constant volatility $\sigma$,
$$ dS(t) = r S(t) dt + \sigma S(t) dW(t), $$
where $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$.
Write $C\equiv C(t, S(t))$, $P \equiv P(t, S(t))$ and $S \equiv S(t)$.
The change of this portfolio, over an infenitesimal small time interval $t + dt$ will be,
$$ dP =  dC - \Delta dS $$
From Ito's lemma, it is known that,
\begin{align}
    dC = \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} dS + 
    \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} (dS)^2
\end{align}
Substitution of this result, in the Equation for the evolution of the portfolio  yields,
$$ dP =  \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} dt + \left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} - \Delta \right) dS + 
    \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} (dS)^2 $$
Here comes the argumentation with respect to the risk of the portfolio (part of your first question). Note that $(dS)^2 = \sigma^2 S^2 dt$ (I leave the derivation up to you).
Hence, the only risk factor, resulting from the Brownian motion, comes from the term $S(t)$. Hence, setting,
$$ \Delta = \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}, $$
i.e. selling $\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}$ shares, will remove the risk due to the Brownian motion within the portfolio. This phenomena is called delta hedging.
The change of the portfolio is therefore given by
$$ dP =  \left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} +  
    \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} S(t)^2 \sigma^2 \right) dt $$
Here comes the part regarding to your second question. Suppose that the growth of the portfolio exceeds the growth of the risk-free asset, i.e. $dP > r P dt$.
At time $t$, we sell the risk-free and buy the portfolio. Note that we have a investment strategy that does not need any initial capital. As the growth of the portfolio exceeds the growth of the risk-free, we sell the portfolio at time $t + dt$ and buy back the risk-free asset. Furthermore, we keep the profit comming from the strategy. As a consequence, we have created an arbitrage and hence $dP > r P dt$ cannot be true.
A similar argument holds for $dP < r P dt$, I leave that to you.
As a consequence, we must have that
$$ dP = r P dt $$
Combining both results yield,
$$ \left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} +  
    \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} S^2 \sigma^2 \right) dt  = r P dt 
 = r (C - \Delta S) dt 
$$
Dividing by $dt$ and using the known expression for $\Delta$ yields the Black-Scholes expression;
$$ \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} +  
    \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} S^2 \sigma^2 + rS\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} - rC = 0 $$

I hope you find it useful.